# When running tests during deployment, are tests ran in parallel?

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, deployment, test-automation

Specifically, I deploy to my org using a command like this:

`sfdx force:source:deploy -u=<accessToken> --sourcepath ./src/main --testlevel RunLocalTests --json --wait 120`

When doing this, do the test run in parallel? Is there a way to specify in the command if we want them or not to be ran like that?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, tests run during a deployment are always run serially, never in parallel.
There is no option to change that.